# Observer pattern with several subjects

Tags: java, oop

How do you design code so that you have observer pattern with several subjects and want to know whats happening?

Obvious solution is

```
interface SubjectOneObserver {
  void update(SomeStateModel m);
}

interface SubjectTwoObserver {
  void update(SomeStateModelTwo m2);
}
```

Then some concrete

```
class Concrete implements SubjectOneObserver, SubjectTwoObserver {...}
```

Not very good, many interfaces will be created. Whats the best approach?

Comment: look into [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Comment: @transporter_room_3, how does that help?

Comment: Since they both have different `StateModel` objects, it's perfectly legit to have it this way. Maybe you could try to combine the different `StateModel`s to one, but that depends massivly on your use case...

BTW: Why is `Concrete` observing two different observables anyway?

Comment: Can't you use [java.util.Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) along with [java.util.Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)? `SomeStateModel` would have to extend `Observable`, for example.

Comment: @SirFartALot, why can it not? I see multiple use cases where an observer would want to be notified by several states

Answer (score 1):

I would use existing interfaces or generic interfaces as an anonymous class (or better a lambda) instead of creating many interfaces and implementing them in the class directly.

Java (8+) already has an interface for your usecase called Consumer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

```
class Observable {
   // there are better ways than using a list, but it shows how the subject would work
   private List<Consumer<SomeStateModel>> subjectOne = new ArrayList();
   private List<Consumer<SubjectTwoObserver>> subjectTwo = new ArrayList();

   subscribeOne(Consumer<SomeStateModel> observer) {
      subjectOne.add(observer);
   }

   subscribeTwo(Consumer<SubjectTwoObserver> observer) {
      subjectTwo.add(observer);
   }

   triggerOne(SomeStateModelTwo state) {
      subjectOne.forEach(c -> c.accept(state));
   }

   ....
}

class Concrete {
   Concrete(Observable instanceToObserve) { // i put that in the constructor, no idea were you get your instance from
       instanceToObserve.subscribeOne(state -> {
           // this will get called when subjectOne is triggered
       })
       instanceToObserve.subscribeTwo(state -> {
           // this will get called when subjectTwo is triggered
       })
   }
}
```

your question is very broad an it is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. Especially how you subscribe the observer to the subject. If you use alot of observables and subjects then maybe you should use library that already has all the features for them like RxJava: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: What if I have 300 different StateModels that I want to subscribe to? putting them all into one `Observable` class seems extremely coupling